# Explain whats different between ImageMagick on Windows and on CentOS linux?

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, libxml2

I have been using ImageMagick running on a Windows 2003 server that is called in a PHP script to create a thumbnail of an image using the following command:

```
$cmd = "convert.exe \"". $fullpath . "\" -resize \"" . res_image_width ."x" . res_image_height . ">\" \"". $fullpath. "\" 2>&1";
passthru($cmd);
```

I have now moved this functionality to a Linux box running CentOS and on which I have installed ImageMagick libxml2-devel :

```
yum -y install ImageMagick libxml2-devel
```

What do I need to change to the PHP code to perform the same action on an image, clearly I can tell that .exe is a windows thang so need to change the path to the linux format but I cannot find the 'convert' file anywhere, in windows it is at C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.3.3-Q16/convert.exe

Do I need to install more files on to the linux machine?

cheers all

Comment: What does 'which convert' tell you?

Answer (score 1):

For OpenSUSE, ImageMagick convert is saved in /usr/bin/

Why not use ImageMagick PHP module? This way your code will be cross-server. Read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Answer (score 0):

To find out where is **convert** just execute

```
which convert
```

or

```
locate convert
```